# PySpark: Check if value in col is like a key in a dict

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to take my dictionary which contains keywords and check a column in a pyspark df to see if that keyword exists and if so then return the value from the dictionary in a new column.

The problem looks like this;

```
myDict = {
'price': 'Pricing Issue',
'support': 'Support Issue',
'android': 'Left for Competitor'
}

df = sc.parallelize([('1','Needed better Support'),('2','Better value from android'),('3','Price was to expensive')]).toDF(['id','reason'])

+-----+-------------------------+
| id  |reason                   |
+-----+-------------------------+
|1    |Needed better support    |
|2    |Better value from android|
|3    | Price was to expensive  |
|4    | Support problems        |
+-----+-------------------------+
```

The end result that I am looking for is this:

```
+-----+-------------------------+---------------------+
| id  |reason                   |new_reason           |
+-----+-------------------------+---------------------+
|1    |Needed better support    | Support Issue       |
|2    |Better value from android| Left for Competitor |
|3    |Price was to expensive   | Pricing Issue       |
|4    |Support issue            | Support Issue       |
+-----+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

What's the best way to build an efficient function to do this in pyspark?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `when` expressions to check whether the column `reason` matches the dict keys. You can dynamically generate the `when` expressions using python `functools.reduce` function by passing the list `myDict.keys()`:

```
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "new_reason",
    reduce(
        lambda c, k: c.when(F.lower(F.col("reason")).rlike(rf"\b{k.lower()}\b"), myDict[k]),
        myDict.keys(),
        F
    )
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
#+---+-------------------------+-------------------+
#|id |reason                   |new_reason         |
#+---+-------------------------+-------------------+
#|1  |Needed better Support    |Support Issue      |
#|2  |Better value from android|Left for Competitor|
#|3  |Price was to expensive   |Pricing Issue      |
#|4  |Support problems         |Support Issue      |
#+---+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a keywords dataframe, and join to the original dataframe using an `rlike` condition. I added `\\\\b` before and after the keywords so that only words between word boundaries will be matched, and there won't be partial word matches (e.g. "pineapple" matching "apple").

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

keywords = spark.createDataFrame([[k,v] for (k,v) in myDict.items()]).toDF('key', 'new_reason')

result = df.join(
    keywords, 
    F.expr("lower(reason) rlike '\\\\b' || lower(key) || '\\\\b'"), 
    'left'
).drop('key')

result.show(truncate=False)
+---+-------------------------+-------------------+
|id |reason                   |new_reason         |
+---+-------------------------+-------------------+
|1  |Needed better Support    |Support Issue      |
|2  |Better value from android|Left for Competitor|
|3  |Price was to expensive   |Pricing Issue      |
|4  |Support problems         |Support Issue      |
+---+-------------------------+-------------------+
```